# Java Applet Background color

Tags: java, applet, background-color

I have created an Applet showing a login page. The code for the Applet is as follows:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

/**
 * Class login - write a description of the class here
 * 
 * @author (your name) 
 * @version (a version number)
 */

public class login extends JApplet

    implements ActionListener
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own

    private JTextField input;
    private JTextField pass;
    private JPasswordField pwd;
    private final String LOGIN = "LOGIN";
    private final String PASSWORD = "PASSWORD";
    private final String CLEAR = "CLEAR";
    private final String Fgt_pwd="Forgot Password";
    private final String REGISTER="REGISTER";
     /**
     * Called by the browser or applet viewer to inform this JApplet that it
     * has been loaded into the system. It is always called before the first 
     * time that the start method is called.
     */
    public void init()
    {
        // provide any initialisation necessary for your JApplet
    }


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        String command = e.getActionCommand();
        if(LOGIN.equals(command))
        {
            input.setText("Login Successful");
           try{
               URL url = new URL(getDocumentBase(), "feedback.html");
               getAppletContext().showDocument(url);
            }catch(MalformedURLException ex){
                showStatus("URL not found");
            }

        }    
        else if(CLEAR.equals(command))
            input.setText("");
        else if(Fgt_pwd.equals(command))
            input.setText("Redirecting to Forgot Password Page");
        else if(REGISTER.equals(command))
            input.setText("Redirecting to Registration Page");
    }

    /**
     * Called by the browser or applet viewer to inform this JApplet that it 
     * should start its execution. It is called after the init method and 
     * each time the JApplet is revisited in a Web page. 
     */
    public void start()
    {
        // provide any code requred to run each time 
        // web page is visited
         // this is a workaround for a security conflict with some browsers
        // including some versions of Netscape & Internet Explorer which do 
        // not allow access to the AWT system event queue which JApplets do 
        // on startup to check access. May not be necessary with your browser.
        Container contentPane = getContentPane();
        JScrollPane sPane = new JScrollPane();
        JPanel pContPanel = new JPanel();

        pContPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints(6, 5, 1, 1, 0, 0, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, new Insets(10,10,10,10), 20, 20);


        Font myFont = new Font("Ariel",Font.BOLD,22);

        JLabel mtitle = new JLabel("WELCOME TO D.A.S.H.");
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        pContPanel.add(mtitle, gbc);
        mtitle.setFont(myFont);

        //Adding the title
        JLabel title = new JLabel("SIGN IN TO YOUR ACCOUNT");
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 3;
        pContPanel.add(title, gbc);

        //Create upper left part for Login ID
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        JLabel prompt = new JLabel("Enter Login ID");
        panel1.add(prompt);
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        pContPanel.add(panel1, gbc); 
       // prompt.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);


        //adding the textfield for username
        input = new JTextField(15);
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        pContPanel.add(input, gbc); 


        //adding the label for password
        JPanel passPanel=new JPanel();
        JLabel passLabel = new JLabel("Enter Password");
        passPanel.add(passLabel);
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        pContPanel.add(passPanel, gbc);


        //adding the password field
        pwd=new JPasswordField(15);
        pwd.setEchoChar('*');
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        pContPanel.add(pwd, gbc);

        JLabel rtitle = new JLabel("NEW USER? CLICK HERE TO REGISTER.");
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 5;
        gbc.gridwidth = 3;
        pContPanel.add(rtitle, gbc); 


        //Now create button for login
        JButton bLogin = new JButton(LOGIN);
        bLogin.addActionListener(this);
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 4;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        pContPanel.add(bLogin, gbc);


        //now create button for clear
        JButton bPassword = new JButton(CLEAR);
        bPassword.addActionListener(this);
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 4;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        pContPanel.add(bPassword, gbc);


        //now create button for forgot password
        JButton bForgotPwd = new JButton(Fgt_pwd);
        bForgotPwd.addActionListener(this);
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridx = 2;
        gbc.gridy = 4;
        pContPanel.add(bForgotPwd, gbc);

        JButton bRegister = new JButton(REGISTER);
        bRegister.addActionListener(this);
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridx = 2;
        gbc.gridy = 5;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        pContPanel.add(bRegister, gbc);


       //adding the panel to the scrollpane 
       sPane.setViewportView(pContPanel);
       //adding scrollpane to the ContentPane
       contentPane.add(sPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    }
```

There is also a paint method which does not contain anything as of now.
The output of the code is perfect. When I try to add Background Color by adding the paint method to the above code as:

```
public void paint(Graphics g)
    {

        // simple text displayed on applet
        setBackground(Color.blue);
    }
```

The output I am seeing is a window with just blue background(in appletviewer) hiding all other buttons and text fields originally shown. If I output in the browser, it shows original output without any background color.

Could you please help me on adding some Graphics (background and text color,possibly an image) so that the applet looks good? (I have to submit it as a college mini project).

Comment: *"..the applet looks good? (I have to submit it as a college mini project)."* 1) Unless the requirement is an applet, code an application.  They are easier. (E.G. - part of the problem above is class caching)  2) Better results will be obtained by putting extra effort into writing clear, well designed, robust code than making a GUI with 'a red stripe'.  Or at least they should.  If that does not apply at your school, your money is being wasted and you should change schools.